# Turn results of a raw SQL query to JSON (and CSV)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sequel, ruby-datamapper

I need to pull data from a legacy SQL Server database and turn it into JSON.  I have SQL queries already written (for legacy versions of reports, that I'm replacing) that extracts exactly what I need.

It is of course easy to turn ActiveRecord objects to JSON (and CSV), but I don't see any good way to do what I need to do, since all the ActiveRecord methods involving raw SQL seem to be aimed at returning ActiveRecord objects, and this data doesn't necessarily logically correspond to a class, and I don't need to persist it anywhere additional.  I just want to perform the SQL query and return JSON and CSV and be done with it.

Comment: there is a railscast for this http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: If you are not doing rails, ruby has a mature `csv` library as well as a mature `json` library, they are pretty straightforward

Comment: if your query returns a list/array of activerecord objects (which I assume it should be doing), then all you need to is call `attributes` method on each elements in the list to convert it to a hash that you can now easily convert to JSON or CSV alternatively you can call `to_json` directly on the activerecord object and it becomes a json object

Comment: I've moved [this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45394/discussion-between-iconoclast-and-bjhaid).  Let's delete the comments here.

Answer (score 6):

in your controller, you could add:

```
render json: @result
```

or

```
render :json => @result
```

and that would render something like this:
 `{id: 1, name: "user name", color: "red"}`

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend `sequel`.

From [Querying with Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/querying_rdoc.html):

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect # database information goes here

class Thing < Sequel::Model
end

result_objects = DB["SELECT * FROM things"].all
```

Then simply parse the result_objects into JSON:

```
require 'json'

hashes = result_objects.collect { |ro|
  ro.to_hash
}

JSON.generate(hashes)
```

Comment: I looked into using Sequel, but I couldn't find anything on making it work with MS SQL.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: [This page](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html) has instructions for using various adapters to connect to your database of choice. Jump to the 'tinytds' section; that seems to be an adapter that should work with SQL Server.